# ASP.Net, How to use Microsoft Chart Control's onmouseover to populate a GridView

Tags: asp.net, mouseover, mschart

I am trying to figure out the optimal way to accomplish, if that is even possible, a master-detail relationship between the markers in the Line Chart (Microsoft Charting) and a GriView on mouseover.

I found an example when this is done with Chart_Click event, using UpdatePanel and AsyncPostBackTrigger. 
However, I'm puzzled about doing this with onMouseOver event of a Chart control.

I need to be able to change GridView based on a value in a Marker on MouseOver.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done only using javascript. Wrap the chart control inside a div and use the mousemove event to refresh the update panel:

```
<div onmousemove="FillGrid()">... (chart control goes here) </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function FillGrid() {
    if (!this.filled) {
        this.filled = true;
        __doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', '');
    }
}
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
    ... (grid goes here)
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your code behind:

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // fill grid code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! I should be able to get marker's value from the sender object then, correct?

Comment: @user1106591 In the code behind method `UpdatePanel1_Load` you should be able to access any property of the chart control.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When Click event was triggered, ImageMapEventArgs were used, and e.PostBackValue contains marker's value that was clicked. How would I determine what the marker's value is in UpdatePanel1_Load when the mouse hovers over it? [UPDATE] Just to clarify, there are multiple markers in a chart, I want to refresh the grid based on a currently selected marker value.

Comment: Maybe you can use javascript to get the element under the cursor and call it's click method.

Comment: You can get the element under the cursor with `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this: this.Chart1.Series[0].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"yourfunction('#VALX');\""; I will accept your answer as you provided a good starting point for me.